# Dynamic form additions and deletions, data with new, UI is not new of antd with React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am stuck in this situation, with React and antd, I want to make a dynamic add and delete forms. with the link below, I make a demo to describe the problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1r51yy68r4

Steps to reproduce

- Add two or three records
- Add data for each record separately (drop-down selection)
- Delete any non-last data
- the one will want to delete is still there

In console, it data is deleted correctly, but the UI is rendering error

reproduce gif:
[image]

reproduce console infos:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting problems because of duplicate key values in the div created on line 120.

In the `handleSelect` function you are reusing the value from the dropdown as the id for the car.

To fix this, you could add another property to your car object to store the id, and create a unique key to use as the id.

```
needUpdatedItem.id = v4();
needUpdatedItem.selectionId = value;
needUpdatedItem.name = fieldNameValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for apply, but the problem still there, It seems on your delete the item, React will render it first, and then setFieldValue success. https://codesandbox.io/s/vq9n1wq4z5